# In NetworkX, how to get the DFS tree including the node data?

Tags: python, networkx, depth-first-search

In a directed graph in which the nodes have not only IDs, but also data (a dictionary of attributes), I'd to obtain the DFS tree starting from a given source node, *including the data* of the child nodes.

I've noticed, however, that the [`nx.dfs_tree`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_tree.html#dfs-tree) function seems to return a tree without any data:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.DiGraph()

In [3]: G.add_nodes_from([(0, {'name': 'foo'}), (1, {'name': 'bar'}), (2, {'name
   ...: ': 'baz'})])

In [4]: G.add_edge(0, 1)

In [5]: G.add_edge(1, 2)

In [6]: T = nx.dfs_tree(G, 1)

In [7]: T.nodes[1]
Out[7]: {}

In [8]: T.nodes[2]
Out[8]: {}

In [9]: T.nodes
Out[9]: NodeView((1, 2))

In [10]: G.nodes[1]
Out[10]: {'name': 'bar'}
```

As seen from the example above, `T.nodes[1]` is an empty dictionary, whereas `G.nodes[1]` contains the data dictionary originally passed in.

How can I make it so that `T.nodes[1]` and other tree nodes contain the same data as the original graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up copying over the data from `G` to `T` using the [`add_nodes_from`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from.html?highlight=add_nodes_from#networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from) method, which updates existing attributes:

```
In [31]: T.add_nodes_from((i, G.nodes[i]) for i in T.nodes)

In [32]: T.nodes[1]
Out[32]: {'name': 'bar'}
```

Any more elegant solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `G.subgraph()`. Extract all the data from the graph with the nodes returned from the dfs tree, like so `G.subgraph(nx.dfs_tree(G, 1).nodes())` This avoids the comprehension list of going through every node individually, and it automatically stores both node data and edge data, while `add_nodes_from()` only adds the node data of graph `G`